# Ошибка PHP \ MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, регистрация

```
// Если ошибок нет, то происходит регистрация 
    if (!$error) {
        $login = $_REQUEST['login'];
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        // Пароль хешируется
        $pass = password_hash($_REQUEST['pass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        // Если день рождения не был указан, то будет самый последний год из доступных
        $DOB = $_REQUEST['year_of_birth'];
        
        // Добавление пользователя
         mysqli_query ("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `email`, `password`, `DOB`) VALUES ('" . $login . "','" . $email . "','" . $pass . "', '" . $DOB . "')");
        
        // Подтверждение что всё хорошо
        echo 'Регистрация прошла успешна';
    } else {
        // Если ошибка есть, то выводить её 
        echo $error;
    }
```

**Ошибки:**

Notice: Undefined variable: error in public_html/php/register.php on line 2

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in public_html/php/register.php on line 11

*Подскажите что делать или как это можно исправить? Просто я здесь новенький..*

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Текст ошибки понятен? Требуется минимум два параметра, дан один. PS. То, что кто-то здесь новенький мало кого интересует. Даже новенький должен уметь читать сообщения об ошибках.

Comment: Ну я уже исправил одну ошибку, но меня беспокоит только этот момент `if (!$error) ` И я не могу понять что он от меня хочет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undefined variable - Значит что переменная для скрипта ещё неизвестна и тем более у неё нет значения, чтобы что-то делать с ним в условии: здесь if (!$error) {

В своём скрипте можете определить значение перменной как true. А там где обработчик ошибок задать ей значение false.